# Inner browser in Worklight App using JQuery Mobile

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use an inner-browser to open a webpage inside the JQueryMobile based Worklight App. Right now I am pushing user out of App to the external Safari browser on iPhone.

I do not have much experience in JQuery Mobile.

Kindly suggest how i can achieve this? Or better workaround.

Thanks

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with jQuery Mobile.
Make use of [Cordova's InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) (requires Cordova 2.3 so be sure to use Worklight 5.0.6).

Comment: Thanks @Idan. Is there any example available for WL?

Comment: It has got nothing to do with Worklight either. It's Cordova, it's JavaScript like any. Look at the Cordova API in the link I have provided. If you have a specific issue, then open a new question with   code sample and a description of what's not working.