# Worklight: Clicking on hyper link within turns screen blank

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, user-interface, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid

I have a simple text on a JQuery Page and have hyper link within it, so when i click on the hyper link then it does open the external browser but in return it makes the App screen white! (blank white), then i have to kill the App and re-start.

I am using Worklight, JQuery Mobile and testing on iPhone.

I am not using WL.App.openURL Or window.open , its just a text coming from DB with hyperlink and on page i am putting inside a Div.

Any suggestion, how i prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code of the link? have you added this attribute to the link? `data-rel="external"`

Comment: i have not added dara-rel="external" . code line is simple, like $("#myDiv").html( textmsgVariable );  Thanks

Comment: I meant render HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you already asked a similar question?
[Inner browser in Worklight App using JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718264/inner-browser-in-worklight-app-using-jquery-mobile/15718537#15718537)

Try using [Cordova's InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html). Clicking 'back' should then return you to the application.

Comment: my question is different one. I have successfully implemented Child browser and its working fine. In this question, I am asking about a text within a Div on JQuery page, in the Div i have hyperlink so when i click on hyper link then above mentioned behavior happens. thanks

Comment: Why not implement InAppBrowser in this situation as well? It doesn't matter what it is... it's a link, and if you want to not lose the Worklight context after clicking it and going back, you need to handle it, and that's what Cordova InAppBrowser (it can also open in the external browser...) allows you.

Comment: Add the implementation to your question, maybe some ideas will spark.

Comment: @AAhad, is this solved? You did not yet add any code to the question.